# How to get the current Id of record in a Form

Tags: forms, axapta, x++

I'm new in ax and have a problem

I have a form with different controls (Id, Name etc..) and a Button.

Click on the button will open a new class to calculate.

Now I want to get the current id, form the form to the class.

Click Method:

```
void clicked()
{
    NewClass newclass = new NewClass("Id123");
    newclass.method();
}
```

The string of "id123" should be the current id from the form, I have selected.

If i use  `select table ...`, I will get any id, and not the selected in the form.
The class have a parm method with a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your class to calculate would typicly have a `main` method, both to make it a target of an (action) menu item and to setup a class object for execution.

The `main` method takes an [Args](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Args_Class) object, then the usual thing is to inspect that:

```
static void main(Args args)
{
    SalesTable salesTable = args.record();
    SalesTableCalc calc = new SalesTableCalc();
    calc.getLast();
    calc.parmOrderRecId(salesTable.RecId);
    if (calc.prompt())
        calc.run();
}
```

In this case it assumes that `args.record` is a `SalesTable` record, creates a `calc` instance of the class, calls appropriate parm methods with the id and finally calls the `calc` object with `prompt` and `run`.

The final point is how to initialize the `record` property of the `Args` object:

- In a form with a `SalesTable` datasource this is easy, just mention the correct datasource on the form menu item control. It may also be correctly defaulted by a surrounding container object setting the datasource property to `SalesTable`.
- Without a `SalesTable` datasource you will have to construct the Args object for use before calling `this.menufunction().run(args);`